# spring batch issues : split my output into differents files

Tags: java, spring, itemwriter, itemprocessor

Hi everyone im pretty new with spring and spring batch. I have a file in input with multiple row and data. I want to redirect the row in a specific file depending to the data in the row. Its something like filter row by data. I saw somewhere that we cant have multiple writer for a step. I dont want to read twice or more my input file. I should have 5 files outputs at the end with 1 intput file. Hope someone could help. Have a nice day :D

my idea was to make multiple steps with different writer and processor but that assume to read the same file N times and isnt very efficient :/

Comment: Nothing prevents you from writing your own composite `ItemWriter` which will call the correct writer based on the input.

Comment: did u how can i have the return of the itemprocessor?

Comment: Why would you need a processor in the first place if you are only splitting. Write an `ItemWriter` which checks the incoming record and dispatchers to the correct writer.

Comment: to determine which rows goes to which file? or i dont need ? im newbie in batch so dont rly know ^^*

Comment: No you dont that is the task of the writer not the processor

Comment: ah nvm, so how can i split and write my date in to different file depending to the data in the input file?

Comment: as stated, create your own `ItemWriter` which dispatches to the correct one.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.